# Implicit Function Theorem, parametrized - can I get uniform domains?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

Consider a family of continously differentiable functions $F_r\colon\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ (where $r\in[0,1]$). For every parameter $r$, we have $F_r(0,0)=0$ and $\partial_2F_r(0,0)=a>0$, where $a$ is independent of $r\in[0,1]$.

Now, using the *implicit function theorem*, we get open neighbourhoods $U_r,V_r\subset\mathbb{R}$ and (continously differentiable) functions $y_r\colon U_r\to V_r$ such that $F_r(x,y_r(x))=0$ for all $x\in U_r$. This is all fine and good, but I am interested in choosing uniform open neighbourhoods $U, V$. In general, I don't think that this is possible but under additional constraints (maybe something like uniform bounds on $\partial_{12}F_r(0,0)$ if $F$ is twice continously differentiable) it might.

I have searched for similar situations but did only find some *global* implicit function theorems (which would do the trick but do more then I am interested in). I also tried to come up with something on my own but am somehow stuck. Any reference, pointers and hints would be greatly appreciated.